# Усыпление потока в зависимости от загруженности процессора c#

Tags: c#, многопоточность, sleep

```
int s = 500;
double cpu = PcPerformance.GetCpuValue();
while (fileStream.Position < fileStream.Length) {        
    s = ...;      
    ReadBlock(fileStream, blockSize);              
    Thread.Sleep(s);
    cpu = PcPerformance.GetCpuValue();
}
```

Допустим, что есть такой код, который считывает файл блоками определенного размера (неважно, что что-то не объявлено, просто есть такой код). В переменную 'cpu' каждую итерацию заносится текущее значение загруженности процессора. Этот отрезок кода работает в своём потоке и может считывать файлы больших размеров(от 5 гигов). Суть в том, что такой цикл сильно грузит проц под сто процентов. И мне нужно как-то усыплять этот поток на определенный промежуток времени, чтобы он не грузил проц более, чем 60 процентов(например).

Comment: [Ошибка XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/184217)? Чтение потока не может грузить процессор полностью. Определитесь, что именно его грузит. Опишете вашу задачу целиком.

Comment: Допустим, что нагрузка процессора может поступать от других запущенных на машине программ. Надо, чтобы считывание замедлялось или ускорялось в зависимости от этого (вместо считывания может быть любой другой выполняемый кусок кода).

Comment: почему тогда просто не проверять значение `cpu` и на его основе вызывать или нет thread.sleep?

Comment: Зачем вам нужно снизить загрузку процессора? Потому что что-то другое тормозит? В этом случае это все-таки задача шедулера ОС, которому надо подсказать приоритет выполняемого кода.